# Programmatically access a svelte-generated CSS class name?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I'm working with an external library (@shopify/draggable) and would like to tell Draggable what the name of the draggable CSS class is in the current component.

```
onMount(() => {
    const droppable = new Droppable(containers, {
      draggable: ".draggable",
      dropzone: ".dropzone",
    });
});
```

Elsewhere, I've defined a `.draggable` style:

```
<style>
    .draggable { ... }
</style>
```

I know I can use the `:global(.draggable)` CSS selector to tell Svelte that the CSS class name is global, but is there a way to do the reverse, and ask Svelte what it would rename the local `draggable` CSS class to once global? e.g. `svelte-a57ab`?

Answer (score 4):

Svelte won't rename the draggable class -- it will still be present in your markup. It will only add an additional `svelte-xxxxx` class to scope the styles, so you may be able to continue using the `.draggable` selector.

However, if you do need access to the Svelte CSS class, you implement it yourself. There is no build-in Svelte API to do this, but you can retrieve it by checking the element's class list. You need to first get a reference to the draggable DOM node using `bind:this` and then retrieve the CSS class from its `classList` in the `onMount` function. Here's an example of retrieving the CSS class from a heading.

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    let heading;
    let svelteClass = '';
    
    onMount(() => {
        svelteClass = Array.from(heading.classList).filter(c => c.includes('svelte-'))[0];
    })
</script>

<style>
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<h1 bind:this={heading}>Hello world!</h1>
<div>
    {svelteClass}
</div>
```

Note that there will only be a `svelte-xxxxx` class if you have applied styles to the node.

Comment: With svelte 4 prefix changed to 's-'